# implementing clean architecture with realtime Firebase in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, clean-architecture

Hi I want to implement clean architecture while using the realtime database but is seems that it is impossible to seperate the database from the my account screen class. Ideally I would want a DatabaseManager class that would handle all database operation (getting reading and posting to the db) but it seems that because the AuthStateChangeListener needs to be in the oncreate of my files it can't work. Does anyone know of any work-arounds? Here is the code I am using this on:

```
public class CreateAccountScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mRegister;
private EditText mEmail, mPassword, mCPassword, mName;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthStateListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.create_account);
    
    //------------------------------------------------------
    //I would want to put this in a seperate class 
    //VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
    //------------------------------------------------------
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (user !=null){
                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAccountScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
    };
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //I would want this in a seperate class
    //------------------------------------------------------

    mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goSignIn2);

    mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username3);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password2);
    mCPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password3);
    mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username2);

    mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
            final String cPassword = mCPassword.getText().toString();
            final String name = mName.getText().toString();
            if (name.equals("") || password.equals("") || email.equals("") || !password.equals(cPassword)) {
                Toast.makeText(CreateAccountScreen.this, "sign up error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            //------------------------------------------------------
            //I would want to also put this in a seperate class 
            //VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
            //------------------------------------------------------
            //DatabaseManager.createUser(email, password, name, CreateAccountScreen.this);
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(CreateAccountScreen.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(CreateAccountScreen.this, "sign up error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference currentUserDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);
                        DatabaseReference currentUserDb2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId).child("connections").child("no").child(userId);
                        Map userInfo = new HashMap<>();
                        userInfo.put("name", name);
                        userInfo.put("profileImageUrl", "default");
                        currentUserDb2.setValue(true);
                        currentUserDb.updateChildren(userInfo);



                    }
                }
            });
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            //I would want this in a seperate class
            //------------------------------------------------------
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: "the AuthStateChangeListener needs to be in the oncreate of my files" There is nothing in Firebase that specific requires this. Why can't you put them in the separate class? What happens when you do that? Can you show a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of *that* problem?

Comment: You have started with a highly coupled example. You are better off following some architecture like MVVM, MVP, MVC - The former being adopted by jetpack architecture. It might make more sense to setup the architecture first rather than trying to refactor to a this highly coupled code.

Comment: If you are interested in implementing a clean architecture, you might consider reading this article, [How to handle Firebase Authentication in clean architecture using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8) or [How to create a clean Firebase authentication using MVVM?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).